# Bash touch - illegal option -d

Tags: macos, bash, unix-timestamp, exif

Yesterday I took a bunch of pictures but I forgot to change the timezone in my camera. Now all pictures have wrong modification date.

I want to change modification date of all files in a specific directory to `minus 10 hours`.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in /Users/slick/Desktop/100D5200/*; do
  touch -r "$i" -d '-10 hour' "$i"
done
```

When I run this script in OSX, I get

> touch: illegal option -- d usage: touch [-A [-][[hh]mm]SS] [-acfhm]
>   [-r file] [-t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]] file ...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not exactly an OSX user but i think that this topic could be useful for you: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99536/changing-creation-date-of-a-file

Comment: what does `which touch` and `touch --version` and `touch --help` give you? i suppose you are not using GNU touch and your version lacks `--d`

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?*  Expecting the availability of a non-standard, platform-specific extension.

Comment: [`man touch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/touch.1.html) is probably worth reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below commands solved my problem:

```
exiftool "-AllDates-=10" /Users/slick/Desktop/100D5200
exiftool "-DateTimeOriginal>FileModifyDate" /Users/slick/Desktop/100D5200
```

Obviously before do

```
brew install exiftool
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using the options for GNU `touch`. You can install it in OS X using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) in OS X:

```
$ brew install coreutils
```

Then it will be available under the name `gtouch` instead of `touch`:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in /Users/slick/Desktop/100D5200/*; do
  gtouch -r "$i" -d '-10 hour' "$i"
done
```

However, the `-d '10 hour'` will not move the timestamp back ten hours, but set the timestamp to the current time minus ten hours. If you want to offset the time stamps, you will have to do the arithmetics for each file.

Furthermore, what you actually want might be to change the EXIF data of the pictures, which would need another tool than `touch` altogether.

Comment: @Camaleo My bad. I didn't know that I had installed it using `brew`.

Answer (score 0):

in the bash script try to use:
$(touch -r "$i" -d '-10 hour' "$i")

it works for me on El Capitan