# How can I create two files of identical size and date modified?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rsync, checksum

We are using some backup tooling that copies files from source to destination. Part of this is MD5 checking the files to see if the contents have changed.

How can I create two identical sized and date created files on my machine with different contents? Is there a script or online service I can use? I'd like to use these for a test scenario e.g.

1. files same size different timestamp = sync files to backup
2. files same size different content same timestamp = sync files to backup

Bash or Python is okay script wise. We are looking to use `rsync --checksum` in combination with `aws s3 sync` at the moment but need to test specific scenarios to be sure these tools do what we want.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a file with a specified size and arbitrary content using `head --bytes=NUM < /dev/urandom >newfile`, where NUM is the filesize in bytes and also accepts a multiplier suffix such as MB or GB (check the manual of `head`). You can run this command twice to make two files of the same size and different content, or just run it once and then copy the file to get files with the same size and content.

Timestamps can be manipulated with `touch --date=STRING`. Either touch both using the same date string, or touch them with different date strings to give them different timestamps.

Comment: A very small addition: `head` can read files itself. If you use `<`, then an additional shell is started which reads the file and makes it available to `head` via stdin.

Comment: Or some versions of `touch` have a `--reference` option that would allow you to set one file's timestamp equal to that of another: `touch --reference file1 file2`.

Comment: Thank you, I just had to refer to this in order to get touch working on my Mac https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465205/bash-touch-illegal-option-d 

The `urandom` file kept thinking it was different when running `aws s3 sync` so I bailed on that part and created two seperate files one with "notepad" the other with "netpad" and then used your touch command to sync up the timestamps. 

I was able to then test aws s3 sync and rsync with checksums correctly. Thanks again.